# Converting Android App Preferences from Titanium to Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, titanium-mobile

We have an app in the store that was built with Titanium. When the user register's their data is stored locally like this:

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('registration', JSON.stringify(regData));
```

We are updating to a new version that is built with Cordova. I am trying to load the old reg data like this:

```
plugins.appPreferences.fetch(
    function(response)(alert(response);},
    function(error)(alert(error);},
    'registration'
);
```

(This uses the plugin [me.apla.cordova.AppPreferences](https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences))

If I install v1 (Titanium) and save the reg data, then update to v2 (Cordova), the error handler is called when fetching. How can I load the existing app preferences?

Note: This works as intended on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AppPreferences` Cordova plugin retrieves Android default preferences like this:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cordova.getActivity());
```

But Titanium stores preferences under the name "titanium". So to load the old Titanium prefs, I added this code to the Cordova plugin:

```
SharedPreferences tiPrefs = cordova.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("titanium", 0);
```

This code only runs if the default preferences are null. If found, I know that the app is being updated from the old version. So, I immediately translate and re-save the preferences with the Cordova plugin. Next time the app runs, it loads the default preferences as expected by the Cordova plugin.